# Change function view_unformatted to work with format HTML list

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have function in template.php which check if image fields exists (has content) and it adds classes if image exists (has_field) and if image does not exist (has_no_field).

This function now works with Unformatted format, but I need it to work with HTML list format. I already tried it with function theme_views_pre_render(&$view) but could not get it to work.

```
function theme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $rows = $vars['rows'];

  foreach ($vars['view']->result as $id => $row) {

    if (!empty($row->field_field_image) || !empty($row->field_field_image_2) || !empty($row->field_field_image_3)) {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] .= ' has_field';
    }  
    else {
      $vars['classes_array'][$id] .= ' has_no_field';
    }
  }

}
```

How to make this work with HTML list format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hook name you are looking for is [template_preprocess_views_view_list](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_list/7) that applies to HTML list views.